# C++ extern: pointer vs. reference

Tags: c++, extern

I have three classes: `ConsoleInputStream`, `ConsoleOutputStream`, `ConsoleErrorStream`. All of them are derived from `Stream`.

Each stream has virtual functions `read` and `write`; as you guess, when user tries to use `ConsoleInputStream`'s `write` member function, it throws an error. Same happens when user tries to use `ConsoleOutputStream`'s `write` function.

Now it's time to show the code.

```
// STREAM.HPP
namespace streamlib {
extern ConsoleInputStream stdin_default;
extern ConsoleOutputStream stdout_default;
extern ConsoleErrorStream stderr_default;
extern Stream& stdin;
extern Stream& stdout;
extern Stream& stderr;
} // namespace streamlib


// STREAM.CPP
namespace streamlib {
ConsoleInputStream stdin_default;
ConsoleOutputStream stdout_default;
ConsoleErrorStream stderr_default;
Stream& stdin = stdin_default;
Stream& stdout = stdout_default;
Stream& stderr = stderr_default;
} // namespace streamlib


// MAIN.CPP
int main()
{
  streamlib::stdout = streamlib::stdin;
  streamlib::stdout.write(); // Still working, but should have thrown error!
}
```

However, everything works perfectly well when I define `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` as pointers instead of references, i.e. error is thrown as expected. But I don't want to allocate/free memory and use `->` operator where I could (could I?) use plain dot operator.

The real situation is of course even more intricated: I also have some other types derived from `Stream` and just want to be able to quickly overload `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` streams with different kind of streams. Is it possible to do it with references?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (I'm ignoring the obvious typos in the header/.cpp side of things, where you clearly have mixed up the stdout/stdout_default)
Not sure exactly what you are looking for here. I _think_ the problem is that you are trying to assign one stream to another, and that in itself is probably a bad thing (in the bigger scheme, you have now "leaked" a reference to the underlying filehandle, or something like that). If that is the problem, then disallowing all assignment of one stream to another would probably make most sense. You can use `private: operator=(Stream &)` to disallow it.

Comment: @MatsPetersson:

I've fixed typos. Could you advice a better way to redirect such streams? I've thought about using member functions `int fd() const` and `void fd(int)` to change file descriptor inside class instance, but that clearly doesn't covers some situations, say if I try to redirect to virtual stream (something like std::ostringstream) which doesn't have file descriptor.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking - what purpose would there ever be to redirect an output file as an input file?

Comment: @MatsPetersson: "The real situation is of course even more intricated: I also have some other types derived from Stream and just want to be able to quickly overload stdin, stdout, stderr streams with different kind of streams. Is it possible to do it with references?"

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do with references. But you need to build the right infrastructure in form of how you actually design your class - which is a different question from the one you have asked here, and we'd need to see your whole class. I would suggest a new question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do with references what you do with pointers, because references cannot be re-assigned. When you do this to references

```
streamlib::stdout = streamlib::stdin
```

it corresponds to an assignment of *dereferenced* pointers, not plain pointers. In other words, if `stdout` and `stdin` were pointers, the equivalent code would have been

```
(*streamlib::stdout) = (*streamlib::stdin)
```

This calls the assignment operator of `Stream`, passing `stdin` to be assigned to `stdout`.

One way around this is to define an assignable "pointer stream" that encapsulates a pointer to a "real" stream, and overrides it on assignment by a pointer to whatever stream being assigned to it. This would let you keep the object syntax, letting you use the dot `.` operator instead of the pointer dereference operator `->`.

Comment: Do you mean to provide a simple wrapper like providing `ConsoleInputStreamWrapper` (probably I need to find another name, huh?) that has `Stream* stream` member?

Comment: @ghostmansd Yes, you would provide a wrapper with a pointer inside. It may inherit from the `Stream`, or have an implicit conversion operator defined to convert that wrapper object to a `Stream` object.

Answer (score 3):

How have you defined assignment on your streams?  With the
reference declaration:

```
streamlib::stdout = streamlib::stdin;
```

assigns what is referred to by the second reference to what is
referred to by the first.

Where inheritance is involved, it is generally a bad idea to
support assignment; in this case, for example, there is no way
that your `ConsoleOutputStream` can become 
a `ConsoleInputStream`, which means that the normal post
conditions of assignment probably cannot be met.  The usual
solution is for the base class to defined a private assignment
operator, and not implement it.  You can also derive from
`boost::noncopyable` (but this will also suppress
copy—which you may or may not want).  And if you're using
C++11, an even better solution is to mark the assignment
operator as deleted.

Finally, with regards to pointers: you don't need dynamic
allocation to use pointers; you can initialize a pointer with
the address of another object.  And the reason it seems to work
with pointers is that assigning pointers results in the pointer
being reseated.  If `a` and `b` are references, then the
equivalent of `a = b` using pointers would be `*a = *b`.